# Get value by position in Redis

Tags: redis, redis-cli

When getting all the keys from Redis, like this:

```
redis.server.com:6379> keys *
1) "z13235jxby03knne1w1gucl5"
```

Instead of manually copying the long key to execute `get z13235jxby03knne1w1gucl5`, I'd like to run something like `get $(1)` (pseudo code) to get the value at position 1, as output by the keys command.

Is this possible, if not, is there any workaround to not have to manually copy paste?

*Note, I don't want to solve this with a script, then I prefer just copy and paste it*

Comment: Do you want to do it using cli only? Or are you willing to use a Python or JS script?

Comment: No, I want to do it through the CLI.

Comment: You could write a little Lua script... https://www.compose.com/articles/a-quick-guide-to-redis-lua-scripting/

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thanks but then I rather just copy paste it.

Answer (score 0):

off the top of my head, I'm not aware of a way from inside the cli.

But, Regardless of any performance implications, you can pipe the cli command lines together , but you have to do it from the *shell*

```
redis-cli --raw KEYS "*" | sed -n 1p | xargs redis-cli GET
```

where the **1** in :

sed -n **1**p
is the line number (1-based index) inside KEYS output.

but still you need to do your validations; like making sure the index is withing the nuber of keys returned by the KEYS command all keys are of simple string type ; not sets, hash maps, etc...